# qiskit transpile NameError

Tags: qiskit, programming

I am a beginner in Quantum Computing programing and I need HELP.
I do not know why the Python or Qiskit does not recognize the "transpile" command? For example,

```
from qiskit import (
    QuantumRegister,
    ClassicalRegister,
    QuantumCircuit,
    Aer,
    transpile,
)

simulator = Aer.get_backend('aer_simulator')

qreg = QuantumRegister(2, 'q0') # greg is filled with two qubits
creg = ClassicalRegister(2, 'c0') # creg is filled with two classical bits

cir = QuantumCircuit(qreg,creg) # we put registers qreg and creg together to make our circuit, called entangled

cir.h(0) # apply the Hadamard gate to the first qubit
cir.cx(0,1) # apply the CNOT gate with the first as the control and the second qubit as the target

cir.measure(0,0)
cir.measure(1,1)

cir=transpile(cir,simulator)
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

Input In [1], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 cir=transpile(cir,simulator)
    

NameError: name 'transpile' is not defined
```

I am using:

- Qiskit Version 0.21.2
- Python Version 3.9.12

In the case the question cannot be answered by this group can you direct me to someone who can help me.

Thank you in advance for your consideration.

Full `conda list`:

```
    # packages in environment at C:\Users\Sirob\anaconda3:
    Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
    
    #
    # Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
    _ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0            py39haa95532_0  
    aiohttp                   3.8.1            py39h2bbff1b_1  
    aiosignal                 1.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    alabaster                 0.7.12             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    anaconda                  2022.05                  py39_0  
    anaconda-client           1.9.0            py39haa95532_0  
    anaconda-navigator        2.2.0            py39haa95532_0  
    anaconda-project          0.10.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    anyio                     3.5.0            py39haa95532_0  
    appdirs                   1.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    argon2-cffi               21.3.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    argon2-cffi-bindings      21.2.0           py39h2bbff1b_0  
    arrow                     1.2.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    astroid                   2.6.6            py39haa95532_0  
    astropy                   5.0.4            py39h080aedc_0  
    asttokens                 2.0.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    async-timeout             4.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    atomicwrites              1.4.0                      py_0  
    attrs                     21.4.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    automat                   20.2.0                     py_0  
    autopep8                  1.6.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    babel                     2.9.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    backcall                  0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    backports                 1.1                pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    backports.tempfile        1.0                pyhd3eb1b0_1  
    backports.weakref         1.0.post1                  py_1  
    bcrypt                    3.2.0            py39h196d8e1_0  
    beautifulsoup4            4.11.1           py39haa95532_0  
    binaryornot               0.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_1  
    bitarray                  2.4.1            py39h2bbff1b_0  
    bkcharts                  0.2              py39haa95532_0  
    black                     19.10b0                    py_0  
    blas                      1.0                         mkl  
    bleach                    4.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    blosc                     1.21.0               h19a0ad4_0  
    bokeh                     2.4.2            py39haa95532_0  
    boto3                     1.21.32            pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    botocore                  1.24.32            pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    bottleneck                1.3.4            py39h080aedc_0  
    brotli                    1.0.9                ha925a31_2  
    brotlipy                  0.7.0           py39h2bbff1b_1003  
    bzip2                     1.0.8                he774522_0  
    ca-certificates           2022.3.29            haa95532_1  
    cachetools                4.2.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    certifi                   2021.10.8        py39haa95532_2  
    cffi                      1.15.0           py39h2bbff1b_1  
    cfitsio                   3.470                he774522_6  
    chardet                   4.0.0           py39haa95532_1003  
    charls                    2.2.0                h6c2663c_0  
    charset-normalizer        2.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    click                     8.0.4            py39haa95532_0  
    cloudpickle               2.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    clyent                    1.2.2            py39haa95532_1  
    colorama                  0.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    colorcet                  2.0.6              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    comtypes                  1.1.10          py39haa95532_1002  
    conda                     4.14.0           py39haa95532_0  
    conda-build               3.21.8           py39haa95532_2  
    conda-content-trust       0.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    conda-env                 2.6.0                haa95532_1  
    conda-pack                0.6.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    conda-package-handling    1.8.1            py39h8cc25b3_0  
    conda-repo-cli            1.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    conda-token               0.3.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    conda-verify              3.4.2                      py_1  
    console_shortcut          0.1.1                         4  
    constantly                15.1.0             pyh2b92418_0  
    cookiecutter              1.7.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    cryptography              3.4.8            py39h71e12ea_0  
    cssselect                 1.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    curl                      7.82.0               h2bbff1b_0  
    cycler                    0.11.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    cython                    0.29.28          py39hd77b12b_0  
    cytoolz                   0.11.0           py39h2bbff1b_0  
    daal4py                   2021.5.0         py39h8cb3d55_0  
    dal                       2021.5.0           haa95532_796  
    dask                      2022.2.1           pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    dask-core                 2022.2.1           pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    dataclasses               0.8                pyh6d0b6a4_7  
    datashader                0.13.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1  
    datashape                 0.5.4            py39haa95532_1  
    debugpy                   1.5.1            py39hd77b12b_0  
    decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    diff-match-patch          20200713           pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    dill                      0.3.5.1                  pypi_0    pypi
    distributed               2022.2.1           pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    docutils                  0.17.1           py39haa95532_1  
    entrypoints               0.4              py39haa95532_0  
    et_xmlfile                1.1.0            py39haa95532_0  
    executing                 0.8.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    filelock                  3.6.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    flake8                    3.9.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    flask                     1.1.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    fonttools                 4.25.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    freetype                  2.10.4               hd328e21_0  
    frozenlist                1.2.0            py39h2bbff1b_0  
    fsspec                    2022.2.0           pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    future                    0.18.2           py39haa95532_1  
    gensim                    4.1.2            py39hd77b12b_0  
    giflib                    5.2.1                h62dcd97_0  
    glob2                     0.7                pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    google-api-core           1.25.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    google-auth               1.33.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    google-cloud-core         1.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    google-cloud-storage      1.31.0                     py_0  
    google-crc32c             1.1.2            py39h2bbff1b_0  
    google-resumable-media    1.3.1              pyhd3eb1b0_1  
    googleapis-common-protos  1.53.0           py39h2eaa2aa_0  
    greenlet                  1.1.1            py39hd77b12b_0  
    grpcio                    1.42.0           py39hc60d5dd_0  
    h5py                      3.6.0            py39h3de5c98_0  
    hdf5                      1.10.6               h7ebc959_0  
    heapdict                  1.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    holoviews                 1.14.8             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    hvplot                    0.7.3              pyhd3eb1b0_1  
    hyperlink                 21.0.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1  
    icu                       58.2                 ha925a31_3  
    idna                      3.3                pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    imagecodecs               2021.8.26        py39ha1f97ea_0  
    imageio                   2.9.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    imagesize                 1.3.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    importlib-metadata        4.11.3           py39haa95532_0  
    importlib_metadata        4.11.3               hd3eb1b0_0  
    incremental               21.3.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    inflection                0.5.1            py39haa95532_0  
    iniconfig                 1.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    intake                    0.6.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    intel-openmp              2021.4.0          haa95532_3556  
    intervaltree              3.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    ipykernel                 6.9.1            py39haa95532_0  
    ipython                   8.2.0            py39haa95532_0  
    ipython_genutils          0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1  
    ipywidgets                7.6.5              pyhd3eb1b0_1  
    isort                     5.9.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    itemadapter               0.3.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    itemloaders               1.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_1  
    itsdangerous              2.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    jdcal                     1.4.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    jedi                      0.18.1           py39haa95532_1  
    jinja2                    2.11.3             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    jinja2-time               0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_3  
    jmespath                  0.10.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    joblib                    1.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    jpeg                      9e                   h2bbff1b_0  
    jq                        1.6                  haa95532_1  
    json5                     0.9.6              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    jsonschema                4.4.0            py39haa95532_0  
    jupyter                   1.0.0            py39haa95532_7  
    jupyter_client            6.1.12             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    jupyter_console           6.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    jupyter_core              4.9.2            py39haa95532_0  
    jupyter_server            1.13.5             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    jupyterlab                3.3.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2                      py_0  
    jupyterlab_server         2.10.3             pyhd3eb1b0_1  
    jupyterlab_widgets        1.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1  
    keyring                   23.4.0           py39haa95532_0  
    kiwisolver                1.3.2            py39hd77b12b_0  
    lazy-object-proxy         1.6.0            py39h2bbff1b_0  
    lcms2                     2.12                 h83e58a3_0  
    lerc                      3.0                  hd77b12b_0  
    libaec                    1.0.4                h33f27b4_1  
    libarchive                3.4.2                h5e25573_0  
    libcrc32c                 1.1.1                ha925a31_2  
    libcurl                   7.82.0               h86230a5_0  
    libdeflate                1.8                  h2bbff1b_5  
    libiconv                  1.16                 h2bbff1b_2  
    liblief                   0.11.5               hd77b12b_1  
    libpng                    1.6.37               h2a8f88b_0  
    libprotobuf               3.19.1               h23ce68f_0  
    libspatialindex           1.9.3                h6c2663c_0  
    libssh2                   1.10.0               hcd4344a_0  
    libtiff                   4.2.0                hd0e1b90_0  
    libwebp                   1.2.2                h2bbff1b_0  
    libxml2                   2.9.12               h0ad7f3c_0  
    libxslt                   1.1.34               he774522_0  
    libzopfli                 1.0.3                ha925a31_0  
    llvmlite                  0.38.0           py39h23ce68f_0  
    locket                    0.2.1            py39haa95532_2  
    lxml                      4.8.0            py39h1985fb9_0  
    lz4-c                     1.9.3                h2bbff1b_1  
    lzo                       2.10                 he774522_2  
    m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2  
    markdown                  3.3.4            py39haa95532_0  
    markupsafe                2.0.1            py39h2bbff1b_0  
    matplotlib                3.5.1            py39haa95532_1  
    matplotlib-base           3.5.1            py39hd77b12b_1  
    matplotlib-inline         0.1.2              pyhd3eb1b0_2  
    mccabe                    0.6.1            py39haa95532_1  
    menuinst                  1.4.18           py39h59b6b97_0  
    mistune                   0.8.4           py39h2bbff1b_1000  
    mkl                       2021.4.0           haa95532_640  
    mkl-service               2.4.0            py39h2bbff1b_0  
    mkl_fft                   1.3.1            py39h277e83a_0  
    mkl_random                1.2.2            py39hf11a4ad_0  
    mock                      4.0.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    mpmath                    1.2.1            py39haa95532_0  
    msgpack-python            1.0.2            py39h59b6b97_1  
    msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1  
    multidict                 5.1.0            py39h2bbff1b_2  
    multipledispatch          0.6.0            py39haa95532_0  
    munkres                   1.1.4                      py_0  
    mypy_extensions           0.4.3            py39haa95532_1  
    navigator-updater         0.2.1                    py39_1  
    nbclassic                 0.3.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    nbclient                  0.5.13           py39haa95532_0  
    nbconvert                 6.4.4            py39haa95532_0  
    nbformat                  5.3.0            py39haa95532_0  
    nest-asyncio              1.5.5            py39haa95532_0  
    networkx                  2.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    nltk                      3.7                pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    nose                      1.3.7           pyhd3eb1b0_1008  
    notebook                  6.4.8            py39haa95532_0  
    ntlm-auth                 1.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
    numba                     0.55.1           py39hf11a4ad_0  
    numexpr                   2.8.1            py39hb80d3ca_0  
    numpy                     1.21.5           py39h7a0a035_1  
    numpy-base                1.21.5           py39hca35cd5_1  
    numpydoc                  1.2                pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    olefile                   0.46               pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    openjpeg                  2.4.0                h4fc8c34_0  
    openpyxl                  3.0.9              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    openssl                   1.1.1n               h2bbff1b_0  
    packaging                 21.3               pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    pandas                    1.4.2            py39hd77b12b_0  
    pandocfilters             1.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    panel                     0.13.0           py39haa95532_0  
    param                     1.12.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    paramiko                  2.8.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    parsel                    1.6.0            py39haa95532_0  
    parso                     0.8.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    partd                     1.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1  
    pathspec                  0.7.0                      py_0  
    patsy                     0.5.2            py39haa95532_1  
    pbr                       5.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
    pep8                      1.7.1            py39haa95532_0  
    pexpect                   4.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_3  
    pickleshare               0.7.5           pyhd3eb1b0_1003  
    pillow                    9.0.1            py39hdc2b20a_0  
    pip                       21.2.4           py39haa95532_0  
    pkginfo                   1.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    plotly                    5.6.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    pluggy                    1.0.0            py39haa95532_1  
    ply                       3.11                     pypi_0    pypi
    powershell_shortcut       0.0.1                         3  
    poyo                      0.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    prometheus_client         0.13.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    prompt-toolkit            3.0.20             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    prompt_toolkit            3.0.20               hd3eb1b0_0  
    protego                   0.1.16                     py_0  
    protobuf                  3.19.1           py39hd77b12b_0  
    psutil                    5.8.0            py39h2bbff1b_1  
    ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_2  
    pure_eval                 0.2.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    py                        1.11.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    py-lief                   0.11.5           py39hd77b12b_1  
    pyasn1                    0.4.8              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    pyasn1-modules            0.2.8                      py_0  
    pycodestyle               2.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    pycosat                   0.6.3            py39h2bbff1b_0  
    pycparser                 2.21               pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    pyct                      0.4.6            py39haa95532_0  
    pycurl                    7.44.1           py39hcd4344a_1  
    pydispatcher              2.0.5            py39haa95532_2  
    pydocstyle                6.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    pyerfa                    2.0.0            py39h2bbff1b_0  
    pyflakes                  2.3.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    pygments                  2.11.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    pyhamcrest                2.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_2  
    pyjwt                     2.1.0            py39haa95532_0  
    pylatexenc                2.10                     pypi_0    pypi
    pylint                    2.9.6            py39haa95532_1  
    pyls-spyder               0.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    pynacl                    1.4.0            py39hbd8134f_1  
    pyodbc                    4.0.32           py39hd77b12b_1  
    pyopenssl                 21.0.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1  
    pyparsing                 3.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    pyqt                      5.9.2            py39hd77b12b_6  
    pyreadline                2.1              py39haa95532_1  
    pyrsistent                0.18.0           py39h196d8e1_0  
    pysocks                   1.7.1            py39haa95532_0  
    pytables                  3.6.1            py39h56d22b6_1  
    pytest                    7.1.1            py39haa95532_0  
    python                    3.9.12               h6244533_0  
    python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    python-fastjsonschema     2.15.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    python-libarchive-c       2.9                pyhd3eb1b0_1  
    python-lsp-black          1.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    python-lsp-jsonrpc        1.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    python-lsp-server         1.2.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    python-slugify            5.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    python-snappy             0.6.0            py39hd77b12b_3  
    pytz                      2021.3             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    pyviz_comms               2.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    pywavelets                1.3.0            py39h2bbff1b_0  
    pywin32                   302              py39h2bbff1b_2  
    pywin32-ctypes            0.2.0           py39haa95532_1000  
    pywinpty                  2.0.2            py39h5da7b33_0  
    pyyaml                    6.0              py39h2bbff1b_1  
    pyzmq                     22.3.0           py39hd77b12b_2  
    qdarkstyle                3.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    qiskit                    0.37.2                   pypi_0    pypi
    qiskit-aer                0.10.4                   pypi_0    pypi
    qiskit-ibmq-provider      0.19.2                   pypi_0    pypi
    qiskit-terra              0.21.2                   pypi_0    pypi
    qstylizer                 0.1.10             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    qt                        5.9.7            vc14h73c81de_0  
    qtawesome                 1.0.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    qtconsole                 5.3.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    qtpy                      2.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    queuelib                  1.5.0            py39haa95532_0  
    regex                     2022.3.15        py39h2bbff1b_0  
    requests                  2.27.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    requests-file             1.5.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    requests-ntlm             1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
    retworkx                  0.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi
    rope                      0.22.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    rsa                       4.7.2              pyhd3eb1b0_1  
    rtree                     0.9.7            py39h2eaa2aa_1  
    ruamel_yaml               0.15.100         py39h2bbff1b_0  
    s3transfer                0.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    scikit-image              0.19.2           py39hf11a4ad_0  
    scikit-learn              1.0.2            py39hf11a4ad_1  
    scikit-learn-intelex      2021.5.0         py39haa95532_0  
    scipy                     1.7.3            py39h0a974cb_0  
    scrapy                    2.6.1            py39haa95532_0  
    seaborn                   0.11.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    send2trash                1.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1  
    service_identity          18.1.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1  
    setuptools                61.2.0           py39haa95532_0  
    sip                       4.19.13          py39hd77b12b_0  
    six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1  
    smart_open                5.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    snappy                    1.1.9                h6c2663c_0  
    sniffio                   1.2.0            py39haa95532_1  
    snowballstemmer           2.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    sortedcollections         2.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    sortedcontainers          2.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    soupsieve                 2.3.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    sphinx                    4.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    2.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    spyder                    5.1.5            py39haa95532_1  
    spyder-kernels            2.1.3            py39haa95532_0  
    sqlalchemy                1.4.32           py39h2bbff1b_0  
    sqlite                    3.38.2               h2bbff1b_0  
    stack_data                0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    statsmodels               0.13.2           py39h2bbff1b_0  
    stevedore                 4.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
    sympy                     1.10.1           py39haa95532_0  
    tabulate                  0.8.9            py39haa95532_0  
    tbb                       2021.5.0             h59b6b97_0  
    tbb4py                    2021.5.0         py39h59b6b97_0  
    tblib                     1.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    tenacity                  8.0.1            py39haa95532_0  
    terminado                 0.13.1           py39haa95532_0  
    testpath                  0.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0  
    text-unidec
```

Comment: You've typed 'traspile' and not 'transpile', i.e. there's a typo in your code

Comment: Thank you very much it was a typo indeed. I changed to: cir=transpile(cir,simulator) and I get the same error

Comment: Please clean up your question and double-check all the spelling and grammar. Also post your code as a snippet with proper mark-down; the question is currently hard to read, contains a large number of typos and/or language-related mistakes and is likely to be deleted in its current state.

Comment: Thank you for your message, I have corrected the question the best I can, sorry about my English, I am not a native speaker.  I posted the code, also.

Comment: Welcome to QC exchange.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the problem regarding the "transpile" looking at one of the examples from Qiskit in this way:

I loaded the package "numpsy" - in the beginning
I removed "pip install qiskit" and "pip install pylatexenc"
I removed "conda list" alo

Thank you to those who gave me suggestions. I'll post the code shortly.
[image: code screenshot]

Comment: Note that you can also accept your own answer as the correct one.

Comment: Thank you R.W I guess that since I was able to run the code till the end as R.W wrote I can accept the answer as correct